# Improve samba speed transfer

Tags: samba

I've just setup a samba server on an old RPI 1. I've mounted a external hard drive, run some tests and got about 20 MB/s speed.

Then did the same thing for my ehternet setup, got around 3,5 MB/s speed between the samba server and my laptop.

Then I tried a file transfer through ssh, went about 450 KB/s sometimes  around 500 or 600. But when I tried to read or write files with samba I am only getting like 200 KB/s at best 250 KB/S. I expected at least a constant 320 KB/s because my purpose with this thing is mainly to store mp3.

So i've tried adding things to my samba configuration file, but it didn't do anything. Considering the value I got from my hard drive and lan connexion I hope reaching 1 MB/s is not too much to ask. What can I do to improve this ?

Comment: what fileystem have you created on the external drive?

Comment: It's an ext4 filesystem.

Comment: Stop using a USB connected drive - the bottleneck is normally a clash over the USB controller bus and getting swamped.  Try a file or two on the SD card and pop the results in your question please. I would be surprised if you can get anywhere near you needs on a Pi 1.  You could try allocating a larger swap but that board is tight on memory.  See https://notenoughtech.com/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-internet-speed/ for some trials.  Do you need SAMBA or just a DLNA feeder?

Comment: I've looked up the DLNA feeder and it fitted my expectations. So manage to setup a plex server and it's working fine.